# My Pygame code for drawing a Tetris setup is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pygame

`settings.screen_tile_width is 10.
and settings.screen_tile_height is also 10.
finally settings.screen_title is Tetris.

```
import settings
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((settings.screen_tile_width * 50, settings.screen_tile_height * 50))
pygame.display.set_caption(settings.screen_title)
bg = pygame.Surface((settings.screen_tile_width * 50, settings.screen_tile_height * 50))
bg.fill("cornflower blue")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    surfers = []
    step = 0
    for x in range(settings.screen_tile_width * 50, 50):
        for y in range(settings.screen_tile_height * 50, 50):
            surfers.append(pygame.Surface(50, 50))
            surfers[step].fill("Black")
            for i in surfers:
                screen.blit(i, (x, y))
            step += 1
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Why is this?

I tried to code this same code (on mac if it works on windows), and it only shown a cornflowerblue background.

And a 500 by 500 window with the Icon "Tetris".`

Comment: Please explain your issue better. Do you have the issue both on Mac and Windows or just one of the Operating Systems? What versions of python or different dependencies do you use in either of the 2 environments?

Comment: Please consult the [help] articles, especially "[ask]".

Answer (score 1):

You used [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) incorrectly. The arguments are *start*, *stop* and *step*. You cannot skip *start* if you want to use *step*:

```py
for x in range(0, settings.screen_tile_width * 50, 50):
    for y in range(0, settings.screen_tile_height * 50, 50):
```

However, for performace reasons, I suggest creating the *Surfaces* before the application loop and to `blit` them in the loop:

```py
surfers = []
for x in range(0, settings.screen_tile_width * 50, 50):
    for y in range(0, settings.screen_tile_height * 50, 50):
        surf = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
        surf.fill("black")
        surfers.append((x, y, surf))
            

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    for x, y, surf in surfers:
        screen.blit(surf, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```